# MVC list not working in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

Is there any additional configuration needed to get an MVC site working in visual studio 2012? My very basic site doesn't display the model.

**Controller:**

```
public class ISPLinkController : Controller
{
    // GET: /ISPLink/Details/5

    public Models.test Details(int id)
    {
        return new Models.test { url = "www.google.com", productGroup = "blah", name = "blah" };
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class test
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string productGroup { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model StopAtNothingAdmin.Models.test

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>test</legend>

    <div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
   ....Snip
```

**GET on `http://localhost:57608/ISPLink/Details/5`**

```
StopAtNothingAdmin.Models.test
```

(that is view source). There is nothing else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return a [View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) from your action:

Assuming that your view is named `Details.cstml`

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var model = new Models.test 
    { 
        url = "www.google.com", 
        productGroup = "blah", 
        name = "blah" 
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

There are plenty of good introductory tutorials on the [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials) site.